# Copying object via pointer and address

Tags: c, pointers

Let's have some pointer to a structure, like `tm`:

```
time_t timestamp = time(NULL);
tm* now = localtime(&timestamp);
```

To create a pointer to a copy in automatic memory, copy by value can be used:

```
tm copy = *now;
tm* next = &copy;
// next points to a copy in memory
```

But why this shortcut doesn't copy the value to a new memory block? (gcc compiler)

```
tm* next = &(*now);
// next points to the address of now
```

This may sound trivial but I'm not sure about the mechanism behind. Why is there a difference?

Comment: is it really possible to copy value using pointers i know about it only reference memory address of some data

Comment: It seems like you need to read (or reread) a good book on C. Here's a [list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to got you started.

Comment: there's no "automatic memory" in C (at least not in the way you want to use it); you have to allocate the memory somehow, and `tm*next = ...` will only allocate memory for the pointer, *not* for the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is only for copying data from one memory location to another. `&` only gives you address of a variable. `*` only dereferences a variable. None of these allocate memory in any form, or create any temporary variables.

All memory allocations must be explicitly stated in C. There is no *difference* to be found here.

Comment: That makes a sense. So when the compiler sees a declaration of a variable, it translates it as allocation of memory on that place?

Comment: @JanTuroň Yes, basically your `tm copy` and `tm* next` allocate memory from stack.

Answer (score 2):

your first example will reserve memory on the stack for the variable `copy`.
it will then copy the content of `now` to the new memory-location, and finally have `next` point to that memory location.

```
tm copy = *now;
tm* next = &copy;
```

the second example will *not* reserve any new memory; instead it will simply assign `next`  the address (`&`) of the object `now` points to (`*`).

```
tm* next = &(*now);
```

the reason they are different, is that C never does any "automagic" memory allocation.
you get what you ask for: if you ask for memory for a variable (as in the first example) you get it; if you don't ask for it, you don't get it.

so the difference between the two examples is really that *declaring* a variable (`tm copy`) is asking for memory.

Comment: Now it's clear. I hope you don't mind I accept the user694733's answer - just because it was the first to see my point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers, as the name suggests, point to a certain place in memory. They do not allocate the necessary memory on their own. You have to do it yourself.

In your code, the pointer `next` is actually pointing th the location in memory, where `now` is is located. If you modify any value through the pointer, you are actually modifying the original structure. That's how pointers work.

If you want to allocate memory, use `malloc` or `calloc`. But remember, that memory allocated like that has to be `free`d.

Once you have allocated the memory, you can copy it by value.

```
tm prev = ...// get the value
tm* now = calloc (1, sizeof (tm));
*now = prev; // copy by value
```

Comment: I know. But I don't want to use dynamic memory management here. I'm just curious why there is a difference between the shortcut and the two-lines form.

Answer (score 0):

With `tm* next = &(*now);` both `next` and `now` will point to same memory location which contains data for structure `tm`.

No new memory is allocated for `next` to point to.

Comment: I know. But WHY the shortcut doesn't create a copy, too?

Comment: @JanTuroň, because its not that operation. It assign value in `now` to `next` which is address that `now` points to.